# Unable to get string from a Bundle

Tags: java, android, bundle

I created a new Activity once a Login is successful. But when I start the app, the app crash within 5 seconds with the message

> `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Error is coming from this

```
name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));
```

---

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    public ImageView bgLogo;

    Button login_button;
    EditText Username, Password;
    String username, password;
    String login_url = "http://192.168.0.19/login.php";
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Enlever la barre bleue
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        initExit ();

        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        login_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogin);
        Username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        login_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                username = Username.getText().toString();
                password = Password.getText().toString();

                if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {

                    builder.setTitle("Mince une erreur...");
                    displayAlert("Veuillez entrer un username et un mot de passe correct...");
                }

                else {

                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {

                                    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                    try {
                                        jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                                        String code = jsonObject.getString("code");

                                        if (code.equals("login_failed")) {

                                            builder.setTitle("Erreur d'authentification");
                                            displayAlert(jsonObject.getString("message"));
                                        }

                                        else {

                                            Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, UserAreaActivity.class);
                                            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                            bundle.putString("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                            intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                            startActivity(intent);
                                        }
                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Erreur", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            error.printStackTrace();

                        }
                    })
                    {
                        @Override
                        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

                            Map <String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            params.put("user_name", username);
                            params.put("password", password);
                            return params;
                        }
                    };

                    MySingleton.getInstance(LoginActivity.this).addToRequestque(stringRequest);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void initExit() {

        bgLogo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgLogo1);
        bgLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    public void displayAlert (String message) {

        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Username.setText("");
                Password.setText("");
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do nothing.
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class UserAreaActivity extends Activity {

    public ImageView bgNet;
    public ImageView bgChat;
    public ImageView bgStats;
    public ImageView bgGo;
    public Button bLogout;

    TextView name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // Enlever la barre bleue
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_area);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));

        initGoHome ();
        initPlay ();
        initGoStats ();
        initGoChat ();
        buttonLogout ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        return;
    }

    private void initGoHome () {

        bgNet = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgNet);
        bgNet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initPlay () {

        bgGo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgGo);
        bgGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, PlayActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initGoStats () {

        bgStats = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgStats);
        bgStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, StatsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initGoChat () {

        bgChat = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bgChat);
        bgChat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, ChatActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    private void buttonLogout () {

        bLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLogout);
        bLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick (View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent (UserAreaActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Replace this code snippet:

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));
```

with

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null)
{
    name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));
}
```

Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String
>   android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object
>   reference

Well, you need to avoid calling a method on a null object. In your case:

```
name.setText(" "+bundle.getString("name"));
```

The bundle is a null object in this case. So it throws an error.
The solution to avoid this crash is to add a if/else statement

```
if (bundle != null) 
   // set text for name like what you have done
else
   // set a default text for name
```

But, I suggest it's better to check your code and understand why your bundle is getting null.

Answer (score 0):

The code is resolved for me by typing
in Activity where you get the value by bundle

```
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    hName = bundle.getString("sharedName");

    b1 =new Bundle(); //this b1 should be declared Globally where you are getting value 
    b1.putString("sharedName",hName);
```

Answer (score -3):

Replace this code snippet:

```
        "class".with(getActivity())
            .using(Album.class)
            .bucketId(Application.getBucketId())
            .entityId(getArguments().getString(YourActivity.GALLERY_ID))
            .retrieve(new XXXX()); Change code : Use Bundle method To replace code below type  Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            "example".with(getActivity())
            .using(Album.class)
            .bucketId(Application.getBucketId())
            .entityId(bundle.getString(YourActivity.GALLERY_ID))
            .retrieve(new XXXX());
```

Comment: The code in the question doesn't contain `NoSQL` class